# AutoCompleteExtender doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, autocomplete, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I want to use [AutoCompleteExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/autocomplete/autocomplete.aspx)

but it doesn't work ,i put a break point in the web service but it doesn't enter the web service !!

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_empName" runat="server" Width="300px" ></asp:TextBox>
                                        <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="txt_empName_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server"
                                            CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement" CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem"
                                            CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem" Enabled="True" MinimumPrefixLength="4"
                                            OnClientItemSelected="get_emp_num" UseContextKey="True" ServiceMethod="Get_Emp_AutoComplete"
                                            ServicePath="~/EmpAutoComplete.asmx" TargetControlID="txt_empName" BehaviorID="ACE_empName"
                                            EnableCaching="False">
                                        </cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

---

My web service :

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class AutoComplete : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public List<string> Get_Emp_AutoComplete(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
    {
        //split the string in the text box to get the department equivalent to the last prefix text entered in the textbox after ',' or ';'
        string[] s = prefixText.Split(new string[] { ",", ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (s.Length > 0)
        {
            prefixText = s[s.Length - 1].Trim();//Last item in the array
        }
        List<string> Emp_List = Get_RequestEmp(prefixText, contextKey);

        return Emp_List;
    }


    public static List<string> Get_RequestEmp(string prefixText, string contextKey)
    {
        prefixText = prefixText.Trim().Replace(' ', '%');
        DBConnection ConnectionObj = new DBConnection(CMSession.GetSession("code", HttpContext.Current), false);

        string  cmdText = "SELECT emp_num , trim(name) FROM grrt5emp WHERE name LIKE '%" + prefixText + "%' ORDER BY name";

        DataTable dt = ConnectionObj.Return_DataTable(cmdText);

        List<string> Emp_List = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            //Returning key-value pair
            Emp_List.Add(AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteExtender.CreateAutoCompleteItem(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString(), dt.Rows[i][0].ToString()));
        }
        return Emp_List;
    }

}
```

---

My AjaxToolkit version is :

```
3.0.30930.28736
```

Comment: Maybe .Net version is mismatch?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik:then could u give me the correct version plz

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/57a357/autocomplete-extender-in-Asp-Net/
I think you're just missing the `asp:ScriptManager`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.